# Solving $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x+ x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} $ without L'Hopitals

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to  0}\frac{x+ x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} $$

This question is very easy by just using L'Hopital's, but I'm trying to do the question without it but I'm stuck on what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Divide all the terms by $x$ and you have the limit instantly.

Comment: Can you use $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac x{\sin x}=1$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x\cos x}{\sin x\cos x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac {x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{1 +\cos x}{\cos x} = 1\cdot\frac 21$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x+x\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac x{\sin x}\dfrac1{\cos x}+ \dfrac x{\sin x}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac x{\sin x}\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1{\cos x}+\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac x{\sin x}$

$=1+1=2$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

$$\frac{x+x\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}=\frac{x(1+\cos x)}{\frac12\sin 2x}=\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}(1+\cos x)\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}1\cdot(1+1)=2$$